# How do I make a list of substrings?

Tags: string, haskell, recursion

I am trying to make a list of all substrings where each substring has one less element of the originial string.

e.g "1234" would result in ["1234","123","12","1"]

I would like to achieve this only using prelude (no import) so cant use subsequences.

I am new to Haskell, and I know some of the problems with my code but don't currently know how to fix them.

```
slist :: String -> [String]
slist (x:xs) = (take (length (x:xs)) (x:xs)) ++ slist xs
```

How can I do this recursively using

Edit: would like to this by using init recursively

Comment: So you want `init . reverse . inits`?  This requires `Data.List`, but you can go look at the source code to figure out how to implement it yourself.

Comment: Also, [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[a]+-%3E+[[a]]) suggests `inits` as the first result for me, and the related `tails` function is in spot #4.

Comment: Writing a lazy version of this function is an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
slist :: String -> [String]
slist [] = []
-- slist xs = [xs] ++ (slist $ init xs)
slist xs = xs : (slist $ init xs)

main = do 
    print $ slist "1234"
```

Comment: Suggested edit: `slist xs = xs : (slist $ init xs)`. `++` is more expensive than `:`

Comment: This lists all substrings starting from 1, but not all substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very lazy version suitable for working on infinite lists. Each element of each resulting list after the first only requires `O(1)` amortized time to compute it no matter how far into the list we look.

The general idea is: for each length `n` we intend to drop off the end we split the list into a queue of items of length `n` and the remainder of the list. To yield results, we first check there's another item in the list that can take a place in the queue, then yield the first item in the queue. When we reach the end of the list we discard the remaining items from the queue.

```
import Data.Sequence (Seq, empty, fromList, ViewL (..), viewl, (|>))

starts :: [a] -> [[a]]
starts = map (uncurry shiftThrough) . splits

shiftThrough :: Seq a -> [a] -> [a]
shiftThrough queue [] = []
shiftThrough queue (x:xs) = q1:shiftThrough qs xs 
    where
        (q1 :< qs) = viewl (queue |> x)
```

`splits` finds all the initial sequences of a list together with the tailing list.

```
splits :: [a] -> [(Seq a, [a])]
splits = go empty
    where
        go s []     = []
        go s (x:xs) = (s,x:xs):go (s |> x) xs
```

We can write dropping from the end of a list in terms of the same strategy.

```
dropEnd :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropEnd n = uncurry (shiftThrough . fromList) . splitAt n
```

These use [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html)'s amortized `O(n)` construction of a sequence `fromList`, `O(1)` appending to the end of sequence with `|>` and `O(1)` examining the start of a sequence with `viewl`.

This is fast enough to query things like `(starts [1..]) !! 80000` very quickly and `(starts [1..]) !! 8000000` in a few seconds.

#### Look ma, no imports

A simple purely functional implementation of a queue is a pair of lists, one containing the things to output `next` in order and one containing the most recent things `added`. Whenever something is added it's added to the beginning of the `added` list. When something is needed the item is removed from the beginning of the `next` list. When there are no more items left to remove from the `next` list it is replaced by the `added` list in reverse order, and the `added` list is set to `[]`. This has amortized `O(1)` running time since each item will be added once, removed once, and reversed once, however many of the reversals will happen all at once.

`delay` uses the queue logic described above to implement the same thing as `shiftThrough` from the previous section. `xs` is the list of things that were recently `added` and `ys` is the list of things to use `next`.

```
delay :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
delay ys = traverse step ([],ys)
    where
        step (xs, ys) x = step' (x:xs) ys
        step' xs []     = step' [] (reverse xs)
        step' xs (y:ys) = (y, (xs, ys))
```

`traverse` is almost a scan

```
traverse :: (s -> a -> (b, s)) -> s -> [a] -> [b]
traverse f = go
    where
        go _ []     = []
        go s (x:xs) = y : go s' xs
            where (y, s') = f s x
```

We can define `starts` in terms of `delay` and another version of `splits` that returns lists.

```
starts :: [a] -> [[a]]
starts = map (uncurry delay) . splits

splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits = go []
    where
        go s []     = []
        go s (x:xs) = (reverse s, x:xs):go (x:s) xs
```

This has very similar performance to the implementation using `Seq`.

Comment: The OP specified *only using Prelude (no import)*. Great answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat convoluted version:

```
slist xs = go (zip (repeat xs) [lenxs, lenxs - 1..1])
  where lenxs = length xs
        go [] = []
        go (x:xs) = (take (snd x) (fst x)) : go xs

main = do 
    print $ slist "1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer to list all possible substrings (not just starting from the root).

```
slist :: [t] -> [[t]]
slist [] = []
slist xs = xs : (slist $ init xs )  # Taken from Pratik Deoghare's post


all_substrings:: [t] -> [[t]]
all_substrings (x:[]) = [[x]]
all_substrings (x:xs)  = slist z ++ all_substrings xs
                         where z = x:xs

λ> all_substrings "1234"
["1234","123","12","1","234","23","2","34","3","4"]
```