# Efficient version of 'inits'

Tags: haskell

That is, `inits "abc" == ["","a","ab","abc"]`

There is a standard version of `inits` in [`Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#g:10), but below I have written a version myself:

```
myInits = f id
 where
  f start (l:ls) = (start []):(f (start . (l:)) ls)
  f start [] = [(start [])]
```

Whilst my version is quite a bit simpler than the standard version, I suspect it's not as good for efficiency reasons. I suspect that when `myInits l` is fully evaluated it takes `O(n^2)` space. Take for example, `myTails`, an implementation of `tails`:

```
myTails a@(_:ls) = a:(myTails ls)
myTails [] = [[]]
```

Which is almost exactly the same as the standard version and I suspect achieves `O(n)` space by reusing the tails of the lists.

Could someone explain:

1. Why my version of `inits` is bad.
2. Why another approach is better (either the standard one in `Data.List` or your own).

Comment: There's a very good discussion of various implementations for `inits` in the [bug report for the ghc 7.8.3 implementation of inits being slow](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9345). The attachment `inits.hs` includes three versions. `initsHO` uses a difflist like `myInits`. A simplification, `initsR  = map reverse . scanl (flip (:)) []`, does the same thing but builds a list backwards and reverses it instead of building a function and applying it. `initsR` was the fastest except when used with evil functions built with `seq`. The queue based version called `initsQ` was fast and robust.

Answer (score 8):

Your `myInits` uses a technique called a [difference list](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list) to make functions that build lists in linear time. I believe, but haven't checked, that the running time for completely evaluating `myInits` is `O(n^2)` requiring `O(n^2)` space. Fully evaluating `inits` also requires `O(n^2)` running time and space. Any version of `inits` will require `O(n^2)` space; lists built with `:` and `[]` can only share their tails, and there are no tails in common among the results of `inits`. The version of `inits` in `Data.List` uses an amortized time `O(1)` queue, much like the [simpler queue described in the second half of a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27512368/414413). The [`Snoc` referenced in the source code in `Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Data-List.html#SnocBuilder) is word play on `Cons` (another name for `:`) backwards - being able to append an item to the end of the list.

Briefly experimenting with these functions suggests `myInits` performs satisfactorily when used sparsely on a large list. On my computer, in ghci, `myInits [1..] !! 8000000` yields results in a few seconds. Unfortunately, I have the [horrifyingly inefficient implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#inits) that shipped with ghc 7.8.3, so I can't compare `myInits` to `inits`.

#### Strictness

There is one big difference between `myInits` and `inits` and between `myTails` and `tails`. They have different meanings when applied to `undefined` or `_|_` (pronounced "bottom", another symbol we use for `undefined`).

`inits` has the strictness property `inits (xs ++ _|_) = inits xs ++ _|_`, which, when `xs` is the empty list `[]` says that `inits` will still yield at least one result when applied to `undefined`

```
inits (xs ++ _|_) = inits xs ++ _|_
inits ([] ++ _|_) = inits [] ++ _|_
inits        _|_  = [[]]     ++ _|_
inits        _|_  =  []      :  _|_
```

We can see this experimentally

```
> head . inits $ undefined
[]
```

`myInits` does not have this property either for the empty list or for longer lists.

```
> head $ myInits undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined

> take 3 $ myInits ([1,2] ++ undefined)
[[],[1]*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

We can fix this if we realize that `f` in `myInits` would yield `start []` in either branch. Therefore, we can delay the pattern matching until it is needed to decide what to do next.

```
myInits' = f id
 where
  f start list = (start []):
                 case list of
                     (l:ls) -> f (start . (l:)) ls
                     []     -> []
```

This increase in laziness makes `myInits'` work just like `inits`.

```
> head $ myInits' undefined
[]

> take 3 $ myInits' ([1,2] ++ undefined)
[[],[1],[1,2]]
```

Similarly, the difference between your `myTails` and [`tails` in `Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Data-List.html#tails) is that `tails` yields the entire list as the first result before deciding if there will be a remainder of the list. The documentation says it obeys `tails _|_ = _|_ : _|_`, but it actually obeys a much stronger rule that's hard to describe easily.

Comment: I previously left a comment that turned out not to be quite right. Note that the described implementation is in 4.7.0.2 and 4.8. 4.7.0.1, which shipped with GHC 7.8.3, had a horrifyingly inefficient `inits` implementation.

Comment: Your comment that "I don't have the patience to wait to see how long it takes to query `inits` deeper than `inits [1..] !! 8000`" suggests you were trying with the old implementation.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks, I updated the answer. Now I have compiler inferiority complex.

Answer (score 5):

The prefix-functions building can be separated from their reification as actual lists:

```
diffInits = map ($ []) . scanl (\a x -> a . (x:)) id
```

This is noticeably faster (tested inside GHCi), and is lazier than your version (see [Cirdec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27674051/849891) for the discussion):

```
diffInits        _|_  == []           :  _|_
diffInits (xs ++ _|_) == diffInits xs ++ _|_
```