# Haskell all possible ways to remove 1 element from the list

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

This is what I've written so far, but I've gotten a bit lost:

```
removeone :: [a] -> [[a]]
removeone [] = []
removeone (a:as) = [as] -- I'm lost here
```

This is the kind of output I'm looking for:

```
removeone [1,2,3] = [[2,3],[1,3],[1,2]]
removeone [1,2]   = [[1],[2]]
```

What would be the best way to solve this problem? In Java I would just loop this and each time produce a new list that I would append to a pre-existing list. I am pretty lost in translating this into Haskell.

Comment: `removeone (a:as) = as : map (a:) (removeone as)`

Comment: @user2407038 Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: @user2407038 I was about to post it as an answer, but now I am feeling bad with that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic recursive solution is given by @сhepner. However, everyday Haskell is not about recursion, it's more about recursive patterns and precise formulation of a problem. If I have got it I would end up with following solution

```
import Data.List (inits, tails)

removeone :: [a] -> [[a]]
removeone lst = zipWith (++) (inits lst) (tail (tails lst))
```

It is more then 2× faster then explicit recursion and seems more like formulation of a problem. Using "dangerous" function `tail` is safe here because `tails [] = [[]]`. Trivial cases are held by `zipWith`, `inits` and `tails`.

If the resulting complementary lists are supposed to be nontrivially processed (say, they represent a view of each game personage in a group) consider Zippers and utilize their comonadic properties (it is really not as scaring as it sounds:)).

Comment: It is worth noting that this solution benefits from the tuned implementations of `inits` and `tails` in `Data.List`. There is discussion of them in [*What are the space complexities of inits and tails?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29393412/2751851) and [*Efficient version of 'inits'*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27672585/2751851).

Comment: This is great answer! This helped me and i understood this very much!

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at a slightly longer example and figure out how to break it up:

```
> removeone [1,2,3,4]
[[2,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,3]]
```

As you already guessed, you simply put `as` (the result of removing the first element from the input) on the front of *some* list, but what list is that?

```
removeone (a:as) = as : ...
```

Looking more closely, you can see that `a == 1` is at the front of each of them. Let's factor that out to see how we might construct it:

```
[[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,3]] == [1:[3,4],1:[2,4],1:[2,3]]
                          == map (1:) [[3,4],[2,4],[2,3]]
```

The second argument should look familiar: it's what you should expect the result of `removeone [2,3,4]` to look like. And just like that, you have your recursive case:

```
removeone (a:as) = as : map (a:) (removeone as)
```